# Accessing AP in a network

Tags: wireless-access-point

Do you have to reset AP to factory default to access it? We have several AP throughout the building. All goes to the same server (pfSense firewall). Now through Netstumbler I notice that some are using the same channels and the subnet mask is not showing on all of the AP. So, I want to access the faulty ones and reconfigure. The problem is that there is no way to access them.

Edited: Sorry about the vague question. We have two NetGear, two TP-Link, , two belkin and two 3Com wireless routers around the building connected to the same server and used only as Access Point. The person first configuring it probably did a good job but my guess it is that since then a several of the routers have been exchanged and possibly moved around. And we've had several IT people since that time. So, after I saw what I mention in my question this I want to try and correct this and make it work good again. But I am very new to it and trying to learn how it works. I thought my best option would be to just enter the misconfigured routers and change it. I've tried to disconnect the routers from the network and access it but it doesn't respond. So, here is my question. Where can I change the channels? And possibly other settings? I thought it would be on the specific AP, so how do I access it? Do I have to set it back to factory default or is there another way?

Thanks,
Nitman

Comment: This question is a vaguely written, and not particularly clear.  provide some editing improvements.  Details about configuration etc will be needed.

Comment: Hopefully this gives more understanding of the problem. All AP have the same IP address. So how do I change configuration of one AP in the network? DO I have to set it to factory default and configure everything again or is there another option?

Answer (score 0):

This answer may or not pertain since the question does not contain sufficient details to understand the nature of the problem.

If you are able to connect to the AP then you're client IP information will contain sufficient information to connect to the AP itself.  Unless it is a customized configuration and not the typical SOHO config.

Once you have a client connected, determine the client's Gateway IP.  This will most likely correspond to the AP.

Plug that IP into a browser, and you should receive a log in or status page.

Once you enter your credentials you will then be able to re-configure the AP.

All this presumes you know the SSID password if any, and the AP administration user/password.  If you do not, then you will need to factory reset the devices.  Once you do that, look in the manual for the default IP/user/password settings and proceed.  Note that many AP's don't default to having the wifi enabled -- you most likely will need to connect via an Ethernet cable.  Additionally, many AP devices do not enable DHCP by default, thus you will need to configure you client IP manually to match that of the AP ... again, refer to documentation of the specific device to learn what these values should be.

Comment: Sorry I didn't put in enough details the first time. Now it is more detailed and possibly more understanding of what I am asking.